# Inject html into thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have thymeleaf templates lying in database,

First I retrieve template and process it:

```
String processedTemplate = templateEngine.process(databaseTemplate, context);
```

So now `processedTemplate` contains `html` as a `String`.

Then I retrieve another template and do basically the same, but I want also inject previous template into it, so the java code should look like:

```
Context context = new Context(Locale.ENGLISH);
context.setVariable("htmlToInject", processedTemplated);
String result = templateEngine.process(mainTemplate, context);
```

So what should I put into my `mainTemplate` to be able to inject another html via `Context` into it?

I saw something like this:

```html
<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header">Header</div>
```

But it works with templates from file, but not when they are lying in database.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds that you want to insert text without HTML escaping, you do that with `th:utext`:

```xml
<div th:utext="${htmlToInject}"></div>
```

Or with *inlining*:

```
[(${htmlToInject})]
```

Comment: Please be aware that utext can be dangerous, especially if you dynamically insert user-generated text. A person with bad intention could then inject malicious code...
(e.g. if you have a public contact-form or the like in the frontend, where user can enter text, which you pass to the e-mail template in the backend).
It should be used with caution (i.e. only with html you have full control)